# Java: Why does an inherited method use the superclass attribute instead of its own shadowing attribute?

Tags: java, inheritance

Trying to dig a little deeper into OOP.

In this contrived piece of code, it is assumed that a character's reputation score of 1-5 means 'not famous', and otherwise if upwards to 10. From the code below, a `Warrior` instance's reputation defaults to 4, a `Swordman`'s to 8:

```
package main;

public class BitOfAPuzzle {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Warrior conan = new Warrior("Conan");
    Swordsman heman = new Swordsman("He-man");
    conan.printReputation();
    heman.printReputation();   
  }
}

class Warrior {
  String name = "";
  /* 0-5 => not yet famous; 6-10 is famous */
  int reputation = 4;

  Warrior(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void printReputation() {
    if (this.reputation >=0 && this.reputation <= 5) 
      System.out.println(name + " needs to perform more deeds!");
    else
      System.out.println(name + " is already famous!");
  }
}

class Swordsman extends Warrior{
  int reputation = 8;
  Swordsman(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  @Override
  public void printReputation() {
    super.printReputation();
  }
}
```

As expected,

```
    conan.printReputation();
```

prints `Conan needs to perform more deeds!`, **but**:

```
    heman.printReputation();
```

also prints `He-man needs to perform more deeds!`, though it should have printed the opposite. Shouldn't the subclass object use its own shadowing attribute for the value, instead of referencing the superclass' shadowed attribute? What explains this behavior?

Comment: You explicitly call `printReputation` from the super class, of course it gives the same result - the only `reputation` variable that `Warrior` is aware of is the one it declares, which is still 5.  (Modify the Swordsman class, remove the declaration of reputation and set it to 8 in the constructor)

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of that question at all. Specifically the question `What explains this behavior?` itself is not answered.

Comment: `reputation` of `Swordsman` class doesn't modify the `reputation` of it's super class, hence it remains 4 that is created inside `Warrior` class, and for any object of 2 classes, it is same.

Comment: The reason the superclass method can't see the hiding field declared in the subclass is encapsulation. If it was any other way, the behaviour of the superclass couldn't be guaranteed, as it would depend on what fields the subclass declares.